# How do I delete a log file with aws-s3 ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3

I'm using :

```
log_file = AWS::S3::Bucket.logs_for('downloads.idance.net').first
```

I would then like to delete each file I operate on, but can't figure out how.

```
log_file.delete
```

throws no method error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this this way:

```
log_file.instance_variable_get('@log').delete
```

the log file has an instance variable that refers to the s3 object.